# CSS child selectors - select 1st nested element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'd like to display only the ***first*** *p.woocommerce-result-count* and *form.woocommerce-ordering* elements. The results are currently being loaded via an infinite scroll and the product count and sort are being loaded with each section so I don't need those.  I've never been good at child selectors so I can't figure this out.  Any help is appreciated. Here is the code:

```
<div class="elementor-widget-wc-archive-products">
  <div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <div class="woocommerce columns-4">  
      <p class="woocommerce-result-count">Showing 1–20 of 319 results</p>
      <form class="woocommerce-ordering" method="get">...</form>     
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <div class="woocommerce columns-4">
      <p class="woocommerce-result-count">Showing 1–20 of 319 results</p>
      <form class="woocommerce-ordering" method="get">...</form>  
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <div class="woocommerce columns-4">
     <p class="woocommerce-result-count">Showing 1–20 of 319 results</p>
      <form class="woocommerce-ordering" method="get">...</form>  
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <div class="woocommerce columns-4">
     <p class="woocommerce-result-count">Showing 1–20 of 319 results</p>
      <form class="woocommerce-ordering" method="get">...</form>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `:not()` and `:first-child` selectors.

```css
.elementor-widget-container:not(:first-child) .woocommerce-result-count,
.elementor-widget-container:not(:first-child) .woocommerce-ordering {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="elementor-widget-wc-archive-products">
  <div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <div class="woocommerce columns-4">
      <p class="woocommerce-result-count">First Showing 1–20 of 319 results</p>
      <form class="woocommerce-ordering" method="get">First ...</form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <div class="woocommerce columns-4">
      <p class="woocommerce-result-count">Showing 1–20 of 319 results</p>
      <form class="woocommerce-ordering" method="get">...</form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <div class="woocommerce columns-4">
      <p class="woocommerce-result-count">Showing 1–20 of 319 results</p>
      <form class="woocommerce-ordering" method="get">...</form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <div class="woocommerce columns-4">
      <p class="woocommerce-result-count">Showing 1–20 of 319 results</p>
      <form class="woocommerce-ordering" method="get">...</form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```